# Catch all route and 404 in rails 2.x

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a `CorsController` whose job it is to respond crossdomain ajax headers (if the Origin is allows) whenever my application receives an `OPTIONS` request.  But because I don't know exactly where that `OPTIONS` request will land, I have a catchall route at the top of my routes file set to catch any `OPTIONS` request to any path.

```
map.cors '*path',
  :controller => 'cors',
  :action => 'index',
  :conditions => { :method => :options }
```

For actual `OPTIONS` requests, this works great.  The problem comes in when the app should be serving a `404 Not Found`.

Now what happens when I load `/no/404/for/you` (a path that my application does not handle a route for), I no longer get a 404.  Instead this route get's activated and I get a `405 Method Not Allowed`.  This is causing our logs to be filled with errors that aren't really errors, and monitoring (like New Relic) to send out panic emails about error rates, when in reality everything is just fine.

It appears to see that the path matches, but the `:conditions` does not, and raises an exception.  What interesting is that it appears the route handling is a 2 pass process.  This cors route, at the top of my routes file, only triggers if there is an `OPTIONS` request (good) or if no other route declare after it matches and there is no static file at that path (bad).

**Question:**

How can I get this catch-all route to hit my controller for all `OPTIONS` requests, without it also intercepting and throwing errors about otherwise unmatched routes via `GET`, `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE`?

*And I need to do this, sadly, in Rails 2.x.*

Comment: `if no other route declare after it matches` Why not adding then a route that matches *everything* else at the end and return 404 ?

Comment: @oldergod Well... Can't believe I didn't think of that.  Though it seems somewhat hacky.  But yeah, it works.  Post that as an answer and you can have the bounty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you say

> This cors route, at the top of my routes file, only triggers if there is an OPTIONS request (good) or if **no other route declare after it matches** and there is no static file at that path (bad).

You could add a route at the very end of your `routes.rb` that would match everything else and just return 404.

As your said it is kind of hacky but I don't see any other way to complete your *catchall route* at the top. Maybe someone will come up with something else.

Comment: This worked. It triggers the controller action one-liner `render :file => "#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/404.html",  :status => :not_found`, which seems to do just the normal thing without making NewRelic freak out. Thanks for the idea!